# How to Stream Live Video Feed from Raspberry Pi to remote server and have server be hub for stream?

Tags: nginx, raspberry-pi, http-live-streaming, rtmp

I am working on a project in which I am taking the video feed from a raspberry pi with a camera attachment, sending the camera live feed to a remote server, and then allowing multiple clients to access the video feed from the remote server.

I have been looking at this guide for potential solutions: https://docs.peer5.com/guides/setting-up-hls-live-streaming-server-using-nginx/

The command that is coming from the raspberry pi to server the video is:
`raspivid -t 0 -w 920 -h 540 -fps 25 -g 75 -fl -o - | ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=44100 -i pipe:0 -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv -f flv rtmp://<server_ip>:<port>/`

The big question is, can I run a pull command like this:

```
application show {
    live on;
    pull rtmp://example.com:4567/sports/channel3 live=1;
    # to change the local stream name use this syntax: ... live=1 name=ch3; 

    # other directives...
    # hls_...
}
```

and just change the pull to rtmp://<server_ip>:<port>/ from the command running on the raspberry pi.

I am trying to do this without the raspberry pi acting as the server.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!